# Explosion animation on Hit Sprite Kit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I wonder how to make add one explosion animation to my game when my character/Ship is hit by an enemy? I've managed to add explosion sound but I want to add a image aswell to the hit on my character, wondering how?

```
 if ([_ship intersectsNode:asteroid]) {
            asteroid.hidden = YES;
            SKAction *blink = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:0.1],
            [SKAction fadeInWithDuration:0.1]]];
            SKAction *blinkForTime = [SKAction repeatAction:blink count:4];
            SKAction *shipExplosionSound = 
            [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"explosion_large.caf" waitForCompletion:NO];
            [_ship runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[shipExplosionSound,blinkForTime]]];
            _lives--;

            NSLog(@"your ship has been hit!");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve an explosion effect you should use a Particle Emitter Editor bundled with Xcode and a [**SKEmitterNode**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEmitterNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKEmitterNode).

> A particle emitter special effect begins with an image file that is to represent the particle. The emitter is then responsible for generating multiple instances of the particle on the scene and animating each particle subject to a set of properties. These properties control aspects of the special effect such as the rate of particle generation, the angle and speed of motion of particles, whether or not particles rotate and the way in which the particles blend in with the background.
>
> **With some time and experimentation, a wide range of special effects ranging from smoke to explosions can be created using particle emitters.**

Source:
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Sprite_Kit_Particle_Emitter_Tutorial

I managed to achieve a really good looking explosion effects in my apps using `SKEmitterNode` and playing with the values in the editor.

Hope it helps.